# physics.addbody() does not work inside a loop in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I am trying to add multiple rectangles in one hit through a loop and here is my code:

```
for i=1,7,1 do
   rec = rectangles.createRoundedRect(left, top, 100, 18, 6)
  physics.addBody(rec , "static", { density = 1.0, friction = 0.0, bounce = 0.2 } )
  left = left + 50
  top = top - 35
end
```

The rectangles are added successfully however they are not treated as bodies (i.e other bodies do not collide with them)

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue
I was using `object:translate()` to move objects while I was suppose to use `object:setLinearVelocity()`

Answer (score 1):

(I think) it's because you keep adding the same rec to the physics engine over and over. Try this:

```
rec = {}
for i=1,7,1 do
 rec[i] = rectangles.createRoundedRect(left, top, 100, 18, 6)
 physics.addBody(rec[i] , "static", { density = 1.0, friction = 0.0, bounce = 0.2 } )
 left = left + 50
 top = top - 35
end
```

And see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several causes for your problem.  Verify that 
a) the boxes are indeed not added to the physics engine (by enabling hybrid physics mode with physics.setDrawMode("hybrid")).  It might be that the boxes are there but you're having issues with your object filters (see http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/10/25/collision-filters-helper-chart)
b) rectangles.createRoundedRect (which I presume is your own function) isn't adding the created objects to a group that isn't the same group as your other objects (if any).  Corona physics do not play well among objects created across groups.